# How to draw pixels for ray-tracing in C++?

Tags: graphics, pixel, trace

I'm currently trying to learn ray-tracing in C++. I am getting help from two books: one is [Ray Tracing from the Ground Up by Kevin Suffern](http://www.raytracegroundup.com/), and the other one is [Physically Based Rendering by Matt Pharr](http://www.pbrt.org/). These two books are great for learning basics and, later, advanced stuff.

I could create some basic shapes using user interface of Suffern's book. However when I tried to write all code on my own, things have gone wild. I realized that I don't even know how to open a window and fill pixels on that. Do you have any good resource to recommend that could teach me the basics of drawing in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could generate image files instead of drawing to windows. The [PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) format is the simplest one to generate. Browsers usually can display PPM. Safari does.

If you want to generate PNG files use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Comment: As I understood, PPM does not support .PNG or .JPEG files, right? What should I do if I want to create one of them?

Comment: I looked it up but it seems too complex for me right now, or I have to have a good night sleep. Thanks though, I'll try to understand it in near future. But it still be very much appreciated if you know any simpler sources for libpng.

Answer (score 1):

SDL might work for you: http://www.libsdl.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate your own image buffer, write your pixels to it, and then save to file/draw to window as needed.  I expect the Pharr book has its own version of this tucked away somewhere, courtesy of Literate Programming.

More concretely:  GUI API's and image file format libraries will typically be able to read simple image buffer data, stored in row-major array order.  I would recommend an RGBA pixel format, something like the following:

```
template<class T> class image_rgba {
  unsigned m_rows, m_cols;
  T *m_data;

public:
  image_rgba(unsigned rows, unsigned columns)
    : m_rows(rows)
    , m_cols(columns)
    , m_data(new T[rows*columns*4])
  {}
  ~image_rgba()  { delete[] m_data; }

  typedef T pixel[4];
  pixel index_pixel_ref(unsigned row, unsigned col)  {
    assert(row<m_rows && col<m_cols);
    return m_data + (m_cols*row+col)*4;
  }
}
```

(note that I have not tested the above -- best to treat it as pseudocode...)